# Wilcoxon Test gives W=0

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data

I am running the Wilcoxon Test on my data, however, I get a W value =0. My questions are two: 1): Why is the case such a test gives 0? ii): How to interpret such results?

Comment: Is there some reason to suppose a value of $0$ shouldn't be possible?  Since interpretation is done in terms of the p-value, please look at the p-value in the output and consult https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes for information on its interpretation.

Comment: There are two kinds of Wilcoxon test: one- and two-sample tests. Which is this? // Do you know how $W$ is computed from the data? // If this is a one-sample test, check to see if all the data are either above or below the hypothetical central value of the null hypothesis. What do you find?

Comment: @whuber: I am using the test implemented in scipy, you can see the documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html. Regarding the first statement, i really don't know whether it to be possible or not. However, i am interested to know why the value is 0 and what it means

Comment: @BruceET : you can find the details about the test here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html

Comment: @BruceET: Moreover, it is  two-sample test

Comment: The test to which you link is _not_ a two-sample test. It can be either a one-sample test or a paired test. I do not use scripy, so I can't track the exact implementation of the signed-rank test. So without seeing the data you're using I can't say what $W = 0$ means. (There are several equivalent implementations in various kinds of software and I don't know how $W$ is computed). Which of scripy's three different  treatments of $0$'s are you using? // I suspect $W=0$ may result if all pairs are positive or all are negative. // Best answer is to take @whuber's advice and interpret the P-value.

Comment: @BruceET: Basically, I am doing a paired test. And the treatment is: "Wilcox treatment: discards all zero-differences", i.e the default one, so all zero differences are ignored. I will share the Data Sample very soon. Thanks for so helpful Response

Answer (score 1):

It is very natural to get a value of W = 0, especially in Wilcoxon matched pair test. This happens when the values of all the observations in the "after" category are bigger / larger / higher than that in the "before" category. This generates all negative differences, and while these would still be ranked, all the ranks will be negative. Since there won't be any positive ranks, W would evaluate to 0.